# how to use if else condition in keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have two text field with id A and B in jsp.Field A take only four digit number.B is date field and is depend on Field A.Field B is display only,as value changes in field A value of B get changed

I am using following js code

```
 $('#A').keyup(function(){


     var number=$.trim($('#A').val());
     var d=new Date();

     var month=d.getMonth()+1;
     var year=d.getFullYear();
     var dDate=d.getDate()+parseInt(number);
     if((year%4!=0) && (month==2 && dDate>28)){
         month=month+1;
         dDate=dDate-28;
     }else if((year%4==0) && (month==2 && dDate>29)){
         month=month+1;
         dDate=dDate-29;
     }else if(month==(1||3||5||7||8||10||12) && dDate>31){
         month=month+1;
         dDate=parseInt(dDate)-31;
     }else if(month==(4||6||9||11) && dDate>30){
         month=month+1;
         dDate=dDate-30;
     }
     $('#B').val(month+'/'+dDate+'/'+year);
})
```

But I am unable to use if else condition in above code.Please give me solution

Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem? I think you need last `else` block instead of `else if`

Comment: `month=month+1;` can simply be `month++;`

Comment: it is not going in if condition

Comment: what is the problem? Can you explain bit more!

Comment: @user100 check console for errors.

Comment: You use wrong syntax: `month==(1||3||5||7||8||10||12)`

Comment: i checked console there is no error.Is it possible to use if or else condition in keyup? Is there is another solution?

Comment: @user100 `2100` is divisible by 4 but not a leap year

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Instead of checking month like `month==(1||3||5||7||8||10||12)`, you can have an array of matching values and use `indexOf` to check if month is equal to one of the value from array.

```
$(function(){
    $('#A').keyup(function(){
         var array31=[1,3,5,7,8,10,12];
        var array30=[4,6,9,11];
         var number=$.trim($(this).val());
         var d=new Date();

         var month=d.getMonth()+1;
         var year=d.getFullYear();
         var dDate=d.getDate()+parseInt(number)||0;
         if((year%4!=0) && (month==2 && dDate>28)){
             month=month+1;
             dDate=dDate-28;
         }else if((year%4==0) && (month==2 && dDate>29)){
             month=month+1;
             dDate=dDate-29;
         }else if(array31.indexOf(month)!=-1 && dDate>31){
             month=month+1;
             dDate=parseInt(dDate)-31;
         }else if(array30.indexOf(month)!=-1 && dDate>30){
             month=month+1;
             dDate=dDate-30;
         }
         $('#B').val(month+'/'+dDate+'/'+year);
    })
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/25/)**